# Kth smallest element in an arra

Tags: sorting, arrays, search

What would be an efficient method to find the kth smallest element in an array with worst case time complexity being $ O(n) $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) with [median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) to find a good pivot so that the total running time is linear in the worst case.